# How to hook Walker_Category_Checklist parameters in start_el() function?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am trying to extend `Walker_Category_Checklist` class.

```
class My_Walker_Category_Checklist extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        var_dump( $args['MY_PAREMETER'] ); // Output is NULL...

        var_dump( $args['checked_ontop'] ); // This is NULL too...
    }
}
```

I need to pass some additional parameters to `$args` array. This parameter is based on post meta and if I will call `get_post_meta()` in `start_el` it will be executed for every element in the list which is not good because elements count is near 500.
Here I have created hook for `wp_terms_checklist_args`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        if ( !empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && ( $args['taxonomy'] === 'my-taxonomy' ) && ( ! isset( $args['walker'] ) || ! $args['walker'] instanceof Walker ) ) {
            $args['walker']        = new My_Walker_Category_Checklist;

            $args['MY_PAREMETER'] = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_data', 1 );

            $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

`$args['checked_ontop'] = false` this parameter is working but it is `NULL` at `start_el` so I understanding that this is different `$args` parameters.
How can I pass additional data to `$args` parameter of `start_el` function in my extended class?
Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

Here ara `var_dump` of `$args` from `wp_terms_checklist_args` filter directly after adding my parameter to `$args`

```
array(5) {
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(14) "my-taxonomy"
  ["popular_cats"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    int(64)
    //...
  }
  ["walker"]=>
  object(My_Walker_Category_Checklist)#3282 (4) {
    ["tree_type"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["db_fields"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["parent"]=>
      string(6) "parent"
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "term_id"
    }
    ["max_pages"]=>
    int(1)
    ["has_children"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["my_parameter"]=>
  string(7) "my-data"
  ["checked_ontop"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

And this is `var_dump` of `$args` from `My_Walker_Category_Checklist` `start_el` function. Here are no parameters which was added in the filter.

```
array(6) {
      ["taxonomy"]=>
      string(14) "my-taxonomy"
      ["disabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["list_only"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["selected_cats"]=>
      array(10) {
        [0]=>
        int(212)
        //...
      }
      ["popular_cats"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        int(64)
        //...
      }
      ["has_children"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
```

**UPDATE 1.1**
Passing args to the `wp_terms_checklist_args` in next way gives nothing:

```
$args['selected_cats']['custom_data'] = array(
    'MY_PAREMETER' => 'wow!',
);
```

This giving a problem when saving selected terms, because `selected_cats` variable is rewritten. `var_dump` of it gives next:
["selected_cats"]=>

```
  array(1) {
    ["custom_data"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["MY_PAREMETER"]=>
      string(4) "wow!"
    }
  }
```

All selected categories are missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thisnk the best solution is to add needed data to the childrens constructor function. It will be called once when `class` will be created.

```
class My_Walker_Category_Checklist extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
    function __construct(){
        $this->myparam = 'my param';
    }
    //...
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        var_dump( $this->myparam );
    }
}
```